# Why scons Copy doesn't copy?

Tags: scons

Can anybody explain for newbies familiar with other scripting languages, why this `SConstruct` doesn't create `acopy.txt` of itself?

```
Copy('acopy.txt', 'SConstruct')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copy()](https://www.scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-user/ch12.html#idp140430764557048) returns an *Action*, to be used in a Builder. You either need to wrap it in a Command() call or, if you want it to always be executed, wrap it in an Execute() call.

```
Execute(Copy('acopy.txt', 'SConstruct'))
```

[SCons man page](http://scons.org/doc/4.0.1/HTML/scons-man.html) should give more info..

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why Copy is not Builder and why things should be so complicated?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, but that wasn't the question, hence my answer.

Comment: Copy() is meant to be an action which can be one of many used by a builder.  All Builders can have N actions.